# Import decimal interval of months with lubridate to convert into days

Tags: r, lubridate, survival-analysis

From a survival study, I have the following pre-computed interval of times as months for overall survival :

```
25.733333  1.000000  1.933333  2.800000  2.866667
```

I would like to import them in lubridate to convert them as days.

Usually I directly work with two dates and I compute as what follows :

```
dataframe.final$Diff.days   <- interval(dataframe.final$Date.First.Immunotherapy , dataframe.final$Date.Death.Or.Last.Contact) %>% as.numeric('days')
```

But in this case, I have only the interval given as a decimal number.

Comment: dmonths(x)%>% as.numeric('days') did the trick